# Calling a stored procedure with a Select statement in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures

Can anyone help me with is situation? I have a stored procedure I want to execute from ASP.NET MVC which will display a select statement from the database. The stored procedure should accept an `ID`, then return some records associated with that `ID`.

Here's the code I have to call it but I don't know how to display it.

SQL code:

```
create procedure sp_members_by_skills
    (@memberID int)
as 
begin
    Select memberID, skill_id 
    from members_skills 
    where memberID = @memberID
end
```

Controller code:

```
SapnaDBEntities dbconn = new SapnaDBEntities();

public ActionResult call_members_by_skills(int? id)
{
    var query = dbconn.sp_members_by_skills(id);
    return Json(query,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

view code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Members by their skills</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.memberID, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.memberID)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.memberID)
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("call_members_by_skills", "Call_procedures", new AjaxOptions {HttpMethod="POST",InsertionMode=InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId="resultArea" }))
{
     <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
}
```

Comment: Are you currently using an ORM framework like Entity or ActiveRecord? Or are you querying the db via ADO.NET?

Comment: What is the problem you are facing ?

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: @BarryGallagher I'm using Entity Framework

Comment: @Shyju I'm trying to display the select statement from the stored procedure.

Comment: @marc thanks I was just going by how I was taught in school kinda a newb

Comment: I assume that you are using ajax to call the controller action since you are returning a json. Can you show us how you call the the action?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Database.SqlQuery` method on your db context object to execute your stored procedure /sql statements. It is always a good practice to do a null check before calling the stored procedure since your method argument is nullable int.

```
var result = new List<MemberSkill>();
if(id!=null)
{    
  var memberParam= new SqlParameter("@memberID", id);
  var result = db.Database.SqlQuery<MemberSkill>("EXEC sp_members_by_skills @memberID"
                                                                            , memberParam);
}
return Json(result ,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Assuming `MemberSkill` is your dto class for your result set. Entity framework will execute the stored procedure and map the result to a collection of `MemberSkill` instances.

As marc mentioned in his comment, you should not prefix your stored procedure with `sp_`